# How to deserialize Json to an object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to convert json to a specific object.

`String : "{\r\n  \"Status\": \"PLANNED\"\r\n}"`

I tried Newtonsoft Json namespace but it is returning a null value.

`var Json= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model Class>(String )`

I want the result in Json format so that I can extract the value from Json as "PLANNED" but I am getting a null.

**PS** :The model class contains two properties , Name (type of string), Value(type of Object)

Comment: I feel someone should point out json is a string, so you arent converting from string to json, but from json to a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var s = "{\r\n  \"Status\": \"PLANNED\"\r\n}";
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusModel>(s);
```

The model you have defined is incorrect.
Your model should be like this:

```
public class StatusModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now value will be extracted to this model and you can access the value like:

```
var value = obj.Status; //"PLANNED"
```

Answer (score 0):

> **JSON Definition**

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language.

[Source] https://www.json.org/

> **JSON Newtonsoft**

Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET .

[Source] https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

**Problem :**

Your are trying to deserialize a json to an object and it's returning a null.
In our context a **Deserialization** is process which transform a json to an object .

`var Result= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model Class>(String);`

The reason why you have a **Null** as result is beacause you are deserializing a json to Model, knowing that you **Json** does not correspond to the **Model** , this is why the **Json** need to correspond to the **Model** so that it can store the information of the **Json**.

**Your Model :**

The model may contain some property that are not in the json and vice versa

```
public class StatusModel
{
   public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Best Regards .

Comment: Your Model class should contain only one property called "Status" of type String

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (using Newtonsoft Framework)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
{
    public class JsonHandler : IJsonHandler
    {
        public IJsonModel ReadJson(IJsonModel model, StreamReader reader)
        {
            try
            {
                string jsonFromFile;
                using (reader))
                {
                    jsonFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(jsonFromFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```